# Is there a way to control VLC from the Sound Menu?

Tags: vlc, indicator-sound

Is there a plugin for this?

I'd really like to be able to pause/play/skip in VLC from the sound menu.

Comment: Have you seen [this post on webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-add-vlc-to-ubuntu-sound-menu.html)? Between it and [this one](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-quickly-remove-media-players.html) you can probably get what you want. Posting as a comment since I've only tried the second one (I don't use VLC).

Comment: @TomBrossman, thats what i wanted! if you make that an answer i will accept it, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Support for this exists in VLC 2.0 and newer. If you have an older VLC you can get the new version by following these instructions:

- [How to update VLC to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version)

First run VLC, then in the menu go to Tools -> Preferences (or just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>.

Then change the preferences to show you all:

[image]

and then go to Interface, Control interfaces, and DBus and check the DBUS service id checkbox.

[image]

Then you'll need to quit VLC and run it again for the setting to take effect.

Comment: I'm running VLC 2.0.5 and this option is not present within 'Control Interfaces'

Comment: Added the VLC daily stable PPA and upgraded to 2.0.6 at which point 'D-Bus Control Interface' shows up with a checkbox in the main 'Control Interfaces' dialog.

Comment: using 2.1.8 and i dont see the dbus even in the control interface

Comment: DBus control removed with VLC 2.1 release. It's started by default/automatically. Commit that removed it: [DBus: remove from list of "control" interfaces](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/commit/4ba6b7dab9fb66fce9967ed979f1b692be18a1f2)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-add-vlc-to-ubuntu-sound-menu.html

webupd8.org seems to be a good blog

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: someone would know how to put vlc keyboard shortcuts, ie example (ctr + s = next track ..) having vlc minimized by placing it in keyboard options shortcuts do not work for vlc