# How to update VLC to the latest version?

Tags: ppa, vlc

As VLC 2.0 is released, how do I get it in Ubuntu (XUbuntu actually, in my case) 11.10? Any PPAs or packages to download? The official page says "Ask your favorite packager..."

Comment: The [PPA mentioned in @Ivan's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/105589/29097) is unsupported. It last [built correctly in 8/2016.](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily/+builds?build_text=vlc&build_state=built) There is no easy way to update vlc. However, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/906472/29097) address this problem with 17.04 and the best you can get is a newer version that doesn't support x.265 with snap. **See [*How do I install VLC 3.0 on Ubuntu Zesty 17.04?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906472/how-do-i-install-vlc-3-0-on-ubuntu-zesty-17-04) for more i

Comment: unable to find `bionic` in VideoLAN's Ubuntu dist list for `stable-daily`, but did find `bionic` in `master-daily`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I've just found [the official VLC PPA](https://launchpad.net/~videolan).

### Stable version snapshots

For the current stable version of VLC that is `ppa:videolan/stable-daily` (currently version 2.0)

Add it to your system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

Update and upgrade / install VLC

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

#### For the daily master snapshots

For the master daily (*testing*) that is `ppa:videolan/master-daily` (currently version 2.1)

Add it to your system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

Update and upgrade / install VLC

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

For more information about PPAs please visit the following post

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: By the way I've already noticed a drawback after installing 2.1 from the PPA: it doesn't offer Mozilla VLC Plugin (and does remove one already installed). That's a pity, I used to make intense use of it.

Comment: There seems to be no repository meant for 10.04 in the PPAs, @sivakumar. stable-daily PPA supports 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) and 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), master-daily PPA supports 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat), 11.04 (Natty Narwhal), 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) and 12.04 (Precise Pangolin). If you really want to update your VLC you can either wait until someone builds stable VLC 2.0 release packages or try using Maverick repo of the master-daily PPA or Oneiric repo of the stable-daily PPA (by editing apt configuration files manually), but I am not sure it is going to work properly.

Comment: This answer should be deleted as that repo has not been built or functioned in at least a year.

Answer (score 17):

Open terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

As of today (2015/11/21), the latest VLC version

**for 14.04** ([vlc 2.2.1](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

**for 14.04  & 15.04 & 15.10** ([vlc 2.2.1](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/vlc))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

Comment: Will not work in 16.04, downvote for not being updated

Comment: How can you expect it to work for 16.04 @rancho Did I mentioned it? pitty on you :(

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1 [unofficial PPA/repository from Rob Savoury](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/02/install-vlc-3-0-12-ppa-ubuntu-20-04-18-04-20-10/):**

1.) Add the [VLC PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/vlc3):  Firstly open terminal from system app launcher. When it opens, run command to add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/vlc3
```

Type user password when it asks, while no asterisk feedback, and hit Enter to continue.

For the **MATE desktop** users, run this command instead to add [another PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/vlc3-mate) with patch from full-screen issue:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/vlc3-mate
```

2.) Add the [dependency PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg4) for updated media tools:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
```

3.) Install or update VLC:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

**Option 2 [unofficial PPA/repository from Panda Jim, Ubuntu Handbook](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/vlc/)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/vlc
sudo apt update
```

**Option 3 [Official VLC Daily Build of master branch](https://launchpad.net/%7Evideolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt update
```

The builds in this archive are fully automated, and do not go through any quality assurance whatsoever. Build breaks and functional regressions occur frequently.
DO NOT USE this archive if you are not prepared to cope with such problems.

As [Jānis Elmeris](https://askubuntu.com/users/216652/j%C4%81nis-elmeris) [commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version/1317483#comment2278449_1317483), you might need to **uninstall various old VLC-related packages first**.

Comment: I get this error when installing vlc this way:
`Sekojošām pakotnēm ir neatrisinātas atkarības:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 3.0.12-3~20.04.sav0) bet 3.0.9.2-1 tiks instalēts
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`. Never mind, I had to uninstall various old VLC-related packages at first.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 14.04 and later VLC can be updated to the latest stable version by installing the vlc snap package. It notably plays MKV, MP4, MPEG, MPEG-2, MPEG-4, DivX, MOV, WMV, QuickTime, WebM, FLAC, MP3, Ogg/Vorbis files, BluRays, DVDs, VCDs, podcasts, and multimedia streams from various network sources. It supports subtitles, closed captions and is translated in numerous languages.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

The vlc snap package will be updated automatically when updates are available.