# How to update VLC to the latest version on Ubuntu

Tags: ppa, vlc

Related to: [How to update VLC to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version)

Except that there are no builds for *Natty* in this *VLC* ppa:

> ppa:videolan/stable-daily

[Index](http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/) of /videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists:

- [oneiric](http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/)
- [precise](http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/precise/)

So how do I update *VLC* (currently 2.0) on Ubuntu 11.04, *Natty Narwhal*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a daily build PPA from the VLC team, add it following these steps

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

Update and upgrade / install VLC

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

[REF](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

Comment: >If you need a more recent version, please consider upgrading Ubuntu. That's unhelpful. The original question was how to locate/install VLC 2.0 in Natty, not how to install 1.x or upgrade Ubuntu.

Comment: Well that didn't come from me it was posted on the VLC web site, so if you think it's unhelpful take it up with the provider. They would surly like your feedback

Comment: How safe is it to use the development branch instead of the stable branch? Also, it is a bit odd that there is a stable version for *oneiric/precise* only, but the development branch contains additional builds for *maverick* and *natty*.

Comment: Have no idea as to the safety. I just know what works, I use. If it doesn't work it gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Installing from source worked for me - here's the log:
http://eumenidae.blogspot.com/2012/02/upgrading-to-vlc-20-on-ubuntu-1104-with.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this PPA, I don't know if they have packages for 11.04, but they have for either 11.10 and 10.04, so it's worth trying.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This PPA is not a testing repo, so lastest VLC 2.0 stable version is released here.
If you still can't get it the easy way, you can always compile from source.

Good luck! ;)

Comment: I do not see any packages except for 11.10.

Comment: Article on OMGUbuntu said so... sorry.

What happens if he downloads the .deb files from this repo?
Like for example downloading core-vlc deb file from: 
https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/vlc/+build/3223046/+files/vlc_2.0.0-1%7Eppa1_amd64.deb ?

Comment: You would also need to install all package dependencies and possibly break your system doing so. Don't be sorry, everyone makes mistakes sometimes, what is important is to fix them after ;)