# How to update to VLC 2.0 in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, vlc

Is there any PPA for to update VLC to 2.0 version in Ubuntu 10.04? If not how can I update it. I have already tried this ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc2
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

and it never works. It just gives the 1.1.13 version.

Comment: Similar to this answer here this should work for you also

http://askubuntu.com/questions/105671/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version-on-ubuntu-11-04/105677#105677

Comment: I agree the down vote doesn't make much sense so I up voted to balance. I would suggest you try and install VLC 2.0 from source.

Comment: Up voted your question. Makes complete sense.

Comment: Still nobody found how to make it work? I also want latest VLC in 10.04 couse ill never use 12.04 couse its slow.

Answer (score 2):

From the [VLC pages](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

**Ubuntu Lucid Lynx 10.04 LTS**

VLC version 1.0.6 in Ubuntu 10.04 is out-of-date. We recommend you install VLC 1.1.x manually.

If you wish to install VLC 1.0.6 anyway, please refer to the instructions above for Ubuntu 10.10. Note that there will be some bugs; you are on your own.

At your OWN risks, install VLC from PPA:

Command line way

```
% sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lucid-bleed/ppa
% sudo apt-get update
% sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

Source: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html

Comment: Op would like to know how to install 2.0 if that is possible, your answer is perfect but does not fit the request from him.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no ppa for VLC 2.0 for Ubuntu 10.04. The mentioned ppa is only for Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric, [as it says](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/vlc).

Comment: Yes, thats why I asked is there any other PPA or any other way to install. For the fellow who marked this question -1, you need to understand the question first.

Answer (score 0):

Add the PPA *ppa:n-muench/vlc2* to your system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc2
```

Install / upgrade vlc

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

([source](http://www.tuxtree.com/2012/02/how-to-install-vlc-2-0-in-ubuntu-10-0411-1012-04-using-ppa-2.html))

Comment: PPA does not contain vlc2, it contains the package `vlc - 1.1.13-1~ppa1`.