# How to install VLC's nightly builds?

Tags: vlc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update VLC to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version)

Hello guys,
I have already installed stable version of VLC from Ubuntu Software center. But i would like to try the latest beta VLC media player nightly builds

http://nightlies.videolan.org/#ubuntu  <-- These ones

How can I do it?

**ty**

**Regards**

:)

Answer (score 3):

First add the repository then you can upgrade the VLC:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Ahh first do i have to remove the Stable version of VLC before i install the VLC nightly version?  Also how do i add the repositories? :/  Sorry im a new comer to ubuntu :]

Comment: No don't remove the old one

Comment: look just open a terminal and copy these commands to. this will install the new version

Comment: Alright thanks so much :) i will quickly respond how it goes

Comment: Ah I used those 3 commands in termanl and it installed. But now when i am opening VLC its showing me Crash Error.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Well i got this windows showing VLC has crashed due to some conflict and it showed an option of Send the details so i did checked that box. And now its not showing that box which shows the details of the crash.But VLc isnt opening :/

Comment: ok revret back to the old vlc. in terminal write these commands `sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily` then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: After pasting this command "sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily" im gettin this error in terminal "sudo: ppa-purge: command not found"

Comment: check your writing. Copy and paste the command sure it's found. **There's no : after sudo**

Comment: Im pasting the exact command still getting the error, here is the screen shot (http://i.imgur.com/GTqPM.png)

Comment: Should remove it from software center??

Comment: ok look open the file `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` and comment the line containing this ppa by inserting `#` at the bnegining of the line then make `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: well sorry i hope im not annoying you, i couldnt understand first paste this command in terminal [sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list] which id did and then list of data started showing in the terminal. Now do i have to paste "#" before this command [sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily] and then paste this command [sudo apt-get update] and then this one [sudo apt-get install vlc] ??  sorry im a little confused :/ but anyway i tried these 2 commands [sudo apt-get install ppa-purge] and [sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily] and it worked.  It has downgraded VLc to previous stable version now

Comment: ok thats great. when i told you about using hash at begining of line ocntaining the ppa we've added. anyway as you have downgreaded back thats perfect and never mind we're here to help each other and share our knoweldge

Comment: Anyway just curious so what could be the reason behind this crash? And forgot to mentiom im using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit could it be because we were installing 32bit on 64bit System?