# Casting VLC to chromecast result in black screen with only the title of the file displayed on TV

Tags: vlc, chromecast

Using VLC 3.0.6 chromecast doesn't work. It connects normally, but video is black and playback isn't going further. It's stuck at 0:00.

Comment: I spent nearly and hour trying to solve this problem.. So I guess it's good to have solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known VLC issue. See post from [VideoLan forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=147617).

> Hi, this should be fixed in the next release of VLC. It was broken with updates from google.

VLC 3.0.6 is broken with chromecast 1.36.140076, but it is confirmed working with nightly `4.0.0-dev Otto Chriek (revision 4.0.0-dev-6281-gaf93e96577)`.

For instructions how to install VLC nightly build, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198077/how-to-install-vlcs-nightly-builds)

Comment: The nightly doesn't work for me either. It doesn't even see the chromecast (doesn't appear in the "Renderers" drop-down).

Comment: @JackM I mentioned specific version, that worked.

Answer (score 5):

It works, just open the port VLC is using. Default is `8010`, go to Tools > Preferences > Show all settings (checkbox down left) > Stream output > Stout stream > Chromecast > HTTP port.

[image: screenshot]

To open the port:

- with `ufw` use:

  ```
   sudo ufw allow 8010
  ```
- with `iptables` use:

  ```
   sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8010 -j ACCEPT
  ```

Tested on Ubuntu 19.04 and VLC 3.0.7.

Comment: Which firewall comes with the default 18.04 ? I hope I can make it work my case too.

Comment: It should be ufw as well.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try.

Comment: This worked for me (I had the firewall enabled). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I have a workaround for this:

1. Start streaming to your TV,
2. then in VLC disable your audio track and the video should start,
3. re-enable the audio track and it will play fine.

Comment: Indeed, just like magic, it works. Had to confirm it would require some conversion when i disabled sound, but yes, after that video came up, and enabling sound again worked.

Comment: You're a legend. How on earth did you figure that out?!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after installing `VLC 4.0.0-dev Otto Chriek` the problem wasn't solved. Then I tried disabling the firewall and voilà! I can play DVDs and stream them to Chromecast. PS: do not disable your firewall, instead allow VLC port in your firewall configuration (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459194/uncomplicated-firewall-blocks-playing-streames-in-vlc)).

Comment: How exactly did you disable the firewall? There are multiple solutions posted in your link.