# vlc depends on vlc-nox

Tags: apt

I am trying to install VLC on 12.04, but I'm running into these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
       Depends: libtar0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix these errors and install VLC?

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: try what @nitstorm suggested

Comment: Doesn't "it is not going to be installed" calls for a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? What about "it is not installable"?

Comment: Try [installing from the official PPA](http://askubuntu.com/q/105587/58950)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Try these commnds :

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then try re installing and see if it works..

And the other option is that, you may download the latest version from [VLC official Site](http://www.videolan.org/index.html)

Comment: Please be aware that the "upgrade" command, if you have NEVER used it since you installed your Ubuntu, will take a very long time to complete AND you need to be on hand to occasionally tap the mouse and/or type "Yes" to a few things.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you fix the dependencies issue and install VLC.

> rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
>
> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
>
> apt-get install -f
>
> apt-get install vlc

Good luck.