# Adjusting subtitle delay delays audio

Tags: vlc, subtitle

This happens only on Ubuntu (since 12.04, now even in 13.04), and happens every time without exception. When the subtitles in VLC are out on sync, adjusting it (either direction) puts the audio out of sync. I think this is because when I resume the video after adjust the subtitle delay, the audio plays, but video doesn't, and then they both continue, and hence the audio is ahead of the video.

Is this a common problem? I was unable to find a fix to this, or even a reference to this problem anywhere. This has happened in each of my Ubuntu installations (and I've done that many times), even on Kubuntu. Are there some drivers I'm missing? Some libraries?

Comment: Do you mean this about self-created subtitles or about subtitles you are watching in a downloaded video resp. in a DVD running with vlc ?

Comment: No, I have a video file and a subtitle file, separate

Comment: are they both two different sources ?

Comment: Different sources?

Comment: I mean - if you have video downloaded from e.g. movie.to - and then downloaded subtitles from different server e.g. piratebay.se or so ? - because it then happens that this does not work together ...

Comment: Yes, my video is from Youtube and subtitles from addic7ed, but why does that matter? When I open the same files on my father's computer (which runs Windows), I am able to sync them without changing the audio-video sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint. Updating VLC from version 2.0.5 to 2.0.8 resolved the problem on my computer.

To get VLC 2.0.8, add the stable version PPA (ppa:videolan/stable-daily):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

To get the daily build add the master-daily PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

To install either, run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Note: The VLC in the Debain repositories is on version 2.0.6

See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) for information about what PPAs are.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this answer to explain how to upgrade `vlc`. (You can edit your answer with the *edit* link under it and to the left.)

Comment: I affirm that this works - I've also added the required information