# unable to install vlc noob question kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

Whenever i type `sudo apt-get install vlc`.
it comes with an error saying that `unable to locate the package`
this is happening with all other installs too, am i making any mistake,
it is my first hour with kubuntu.

Comment: did you add the PPA repository for vlc?

Comment: Dumb question, but are you connected to the internet? Linux software management always tries to fetch the latest version from the online repositories.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/105589/48105) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then retry (Also I assume you mean `apt-get install` not `app-get install`?)

Comment: `app-get install` doesn't shows `unable to locate the package` error