# How to install VLC 2.2.1 in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, vlc

I want to install VLC 2.2.1 which is the current stable version.

I've followed the instructions from [How to update VLC to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version) but it only installs VLC 2.2.0 which is the same version than the one from the Ubuntu Software Center :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: You will have to either wait for the PPA to be updated or build it yourself from source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this with [n-muench vlc ppa](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/vlc) but do read all the warnings and notations from the PPA, as you'll be taking any risk for any damages at your own risk.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will upgrade your installed vlc version to 2.2.1 if you don't have any installed then after the above commands run:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```