# Installing a specific version of VLC from a PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, vlc

I'm trying to install a specific version of vlc (2.2.x)

I've added the PPA repository according to this question: [How to update VLC to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version). I've remembered to issue the command `sudo apt-get update`

However, I still only get the 1.6 version from the general trusty repository. Even though in the html page of the repository the version is there: https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily

Not my regular package manager, synaptic, or good-old CLI `apt-get` sees the version from the PPA I've added.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
using Mint 17.1 (Based on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty)

Output of `apt-cache policy vlc`

```
vlc:
 Installé : (aucun)
 Candidat : 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
 Table de version :
     2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     2.1.4+git20150226+r54594+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy vlc`.

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and run: (for 14.04)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no version >2.1 for Trusty in the PPA `ppa:videolan/stable-daily`
available and you have added this PPA to your system.

You can install VLC with the version `2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1` via

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

available in the Ubuntu Universe repositories. Or use [@Ravan](https://askubuntu.com/users/439451/ravan)s answer and enable another [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/677444/367165).