# very basic question about ppa

Tags: ppa, vlc

What is a *ppa*? I tried installing `vlc 2.2.1` but I found two PPAs and both of them seem to work? Is there no difference between them? Which one is better for future releases?

1. ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
   sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
   ```
2. ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
   sudo apt-get install vlc
   ```

Also, why is `sudo apt-get update` always included in the steps of installing new software? Isn't Ubuntu supposed to be updated by its nature ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that `ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` is available only for trusty.

The official PPA is `ppa:videolan/stable-daily` and currently available for 12.04,14.04,15.04.

Please refer [ubuntu/trusty-media](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) and [ubuntu/stable-daily](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily)

---

`apt-add-repository` with a PPA as argument just adds a file into `/etc/apt/source.list.d`

`apt-get update` updates the packages to include the new repository.

Please refer [AptGet/Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

<sub>Note : There is another PPA available for VLC as well - please refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version/677450#677450)</sub>

Comment: so the second one is better since it works on more than one version. I guess I'll use it from now on. I'll also include vlc-plugin-* with the second ppa.

Comment: If you are using trusty..second one give 2.1 ..@raudbul

Comment: follow through my linked post at the end  =) @raudbul

Comment: sorry about that. will use the one u referred me to.

Comment: I am using Lubuntu 14.04 LTS by the way and I am going to upgrade to 16.04 LTS when it comes out (https://goo.gl/a4pBJJ). I will probably have to look for a new ppa, right ? Not that it matters, but I just want to know if it's guaranteed to always work or it's just a matter of probability.

Comment: @raudbul PPA's will work fine AFAIK-btw you can see in launchpad page,regarding any ppa..(ups in the sense +1 ;)=)