# VLC 3.0 Not installing PPA not found

Tags: ppa, vlc

I have been trying for a while to install vlc 3.0 on ubuntu 17.10, with no luck. I even installed the snap version but it doesn't seem to play videos outside of the home folder, so I can't view videos on my other partitions.

Thing is, when I try to install vlc 3.0 from the stable PPA, I get vlc 2.2.6 instead. After adding the PPA and run sudo apt-get update, I get the following error

```
 E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I have tried removing the PPA and adding it back but it still says the same thing. Am I missing something

EDIT: I have tried the solution from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version) but I still get the release file not found error

Comment: As per edit the dupe doesn't work.  Snap is the only way to go.  I can play files from outside the home folder just fine with the snap version.  What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

Remove VLC PPAs and revert it to the version from repository:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

These actions are needed because of the fact that PPAs do not have packages for Artful anymore.

Then remove vlc snap

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

And install it again with `--classic` option:

```
sudo snap install --classic vlc
```

Comment: I tried installing snap with the --classic version but it still doesn't play videos outside the home directory

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that the best solution would be to upgrade to Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS as it has [VLC 3.0.1 in the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=vlc).

Comment: I thought that version wasn't out until 26th. That was when I planned on upgrading.