# Can't install vlc 4.0.0 nightly build

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, vlc

I would like to install vlc 4.0 nightly build. But for some unknown reason i can't move from version 3.0.8.

I followed this post
[How to update VLC to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version/105589#105589)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

But when i call `sudo apt-cache policy vlc` i get only version 3.

```
vlc:
  Instalovaná verze: 3.0.8-0ubuntu18.04.1
  Kandidát:          3.0.8-0ubuntu18.04.1
  Tabulka verzí:
 *** 3.0.8-0ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.1-3build1 500
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Do I missing something?

Comment: I might be mistaken but it looks as though they have only done the 4.0.0 versions for 19.04, 19.10 and 20.04.  https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily  As a test I tried it on both 18.04 and 19.10, and 19.10 would allow it for installation.

Comment: Oh, i didnt think of that :/ Thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) mentioned in comments, videolan done version 4.0.0 for Ubuntu for 19.04, 19.10 and 20.04. Thanks mate