# integrate VLC 2 in the sound menu

Tags: 11.10, vlc, indicator-sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to control VLC from the Sound Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40107/is-there-a-way-to-control-vlc-from-the-sound-menu)

How to integrate VLC control 2 in the sound menu Ubuntu 11.10? I activated the VLC options of MPRISv2 and nothing happens.