# Sound menu keyboard shortcuts aren't working with VLC. Work fine with Rhythmbox/Banshee

Tags: shortcut-keys, vlc, indicator-sound, dbus

I enabled vlc dbus interface:

[Is there a way to control VLC from the Sound Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40107/is-there-a-way-to-control-vlc-from-the-sound-menu)

VLC now appears in the sound menu and the controls work.

However, the keyboard shortcuts configured for the media player (System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Sound and Media) for Play, "Next Track" and "previous track" aren't working. They work fine with banshee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command in comments seems fine. Best way to set, if using compiz, is in ccsm > `Commands`. (you also need to have the `dbus plugin` enabled.

Then for command enter as commented `dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause`

Enable it to the media key in the key bindings as seen in screen, here it's run command 2, when going to the set 'key combo', I just used the media play/pause on keyboard, ie. no combo

[image]

Comment: Yes. That's an option. Doing so makes it vlc specific, while the system shortcuts don't. I mainly use vlc for audio, video. If I can't make the system shortcuts work, defining custom commands for vlc specific dbus methods is the next best thing.

Comment: When I run the command in shell, it says: `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc was not provided by any .service files` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, first I had to enable `Interface > Control Interface > D-Bus control interface`, then restart `vlc`, and now it works. I didn't enable `dbus plugin` if I understand you correctly. I'm talking about `D-Bus (D-Bus Control Backend)`, the same kind of thing as `Commands (Assigns bindings to arbitrary commands)`. I'm running `vlc-2.0.8`, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

ASAIT, VLC cannot be bind to System Audio shortcuts like Rhythmbox or Banshee or Totem.
It has its own HOTKEYS interface.
The only way I found is the Playlist Hotkeys thing:

- Press N for Next audio/video track
- Press P for Previous audio/video track
- Press SPACE to pause/play track
- Press S to stop track.

Though, the **VLC Window should be active** in order for the hotkeys to be active too.

And **D-BUS triggering:**

**Play/Pause Track command:**

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
```

**Stop Playing command:**

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Stop
```

Next Track command:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
```

**Previous Track command:**

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous
```

VlC Dbus commands added as shorcuts in Unity launcher for VLC entry (using Ubuntu Tweak

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

)

[image: VLC Custom Shortcuts in Unity Launcher]

**VLC Hotkeys**

[image: VLC Hotkeys]

If you try to bind the Multimedia Bios/System keyboard keys to VLC you'd get either a conflict or the latter would be overwritten/lost. That's my case.
For the time being, spot some free keyboard shortcuts and bind them to vlc mpris/vlc methods.

Comment: I know about vlc keybindings. I am interested in system keybindings to control vlc.

I am still looking into it, so I am not sure either. But considering that banshee is controlled using the dbus interface, and vlc can be controlled using dbus, I think it should be doable and I am missing something.

`dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause`