# How do I add VLC to music menu along with Banshee and others?

Tags: indicator, vlc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to control VLC from the Sound Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40107/is-there-a-way-to-control-vlc-from-the-sound-menu)

I use VLC player more often than Banshee, so is there any way to make VLC appear in music menu?